# php array's making the Undefined index: 0 notice go away

Tags: php, arrays, e-notices

Right so i have E_NOTICES on and my code works its just i keep getting "Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: 0" everytime i try to insert my data into the array with the set key. Its really annoying when ur trying to debug.

What am i doing wrong that will make the notices go away without turning off E_NOTICES?

```
foreach ($bracketmatches->result() as $row)
{
  if(!isset($bracketdata[$row->position])) 
  {
    $bracketdata[$row->position] = array(); 
  }
  $bracketdata[$row->position] = array("home_name" => $teams[$row->home_id]['team_name']);
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the notice on?  Is it the if statement?  Or the last assignment line?

Comment: The whole if thing looks redundant since you set `$bracketdata[$row->position]` anyway.

Comment: The whole `if{}` block is redundant, since you are assigning an array() either way. Your issue is that there's nothing in `$team[0]`. And I would rather not make that specific notice "go away", but investigate why nothing is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `$teams[$row->home_id]` definitely defined?

edit: Quick and dirty test for you:

```
foreach ($bracketmatches->result() as $row)
{
  if(!isset($teams[$row->home_id]))
  {
    die('GOTCHA!!!');
  }
  $bracketdata[$row->position] = array("home_name" => $teams[$row->home_id]['team_name']);
}
```

Comment: My bad i was rushing to go out and watch the football and didnt set home_id in the database so it was looking for the array key 0 and that didnt exist in the team data. Thanks for the dirty test :P it helped

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say for certain without more information, but I would check that $row->position is set and that $row->home_id is set if there is any possibility they may be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the base array before pushing values to it. The isset here doesn't really do anything. Just throw it away. If you still get the error make sure `$teams[$row->home_id]['team_name']` is always set.

```
$bracketdata = array();
foreach ($bracketmatches->result() as $row)
{
  $bracketdata[$row->position] = array("home_name" => $teams[$row->home_id]['team_name']);
}
```

Comment: That specific notice `Undefined index: 0` doesn't sound like it has anything to do with initializing the array or not.

Comment: Thinking about it I think you're right. `$bracketdata` should still be initialized before usage though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bracketdata = array();
foreach ($bracketmatches->result() as $row)
{
  if (isset($row->position) && !empty($row->position) && isset($teams[$row->home_id]['team_name']))
     $bracketdata[$row->position] = array("home_name" => $teams[$row->home_id]['team_name']);
}
```